# Reset SMC: Can I use "SMCFlasher.efi -reset 1"?

Tags: power-management, efi

I'm in a situation where I don't have working internal shift+ctrl+alt-keys and thusly unable to perform SMC-reset.

Related to others' issues with SMC-updates, there are instructions for re-flashing the firmware using rEFIt and utilities extracted from the official updater. One of the steps are:

```
SmcFlasher.efi -reset 1
```

With the description

> First need to get the SMC into the right state.
>   "SmcFlasher.efi -reset 1".
>   Your MBP fans should now quiet down.

[Source](https://discussions.apple.com/message/22024754#22024754)

This is indicative of an SMC-reset.

Does anyone have experience with using this command? Does it in fact reset SMC, or is it a potentially destructive command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can verify that this procedure does indeed reset SMC. It will give a warning-message, but this is unrelated. Fans, charging and everything else goes back to normal, as with a keyboard-triggered SMC-reset.